# How do I add a legend without using aes() in R with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm currently plotting a double axis graph using a bar chart and line graph, and want to add a legend at the bottom of the chart to show that the blue bar chart represents new constructions and the orange line signifies average rental prices. However, I am unable to do so in ggplot. Usually we use aes(color=[variable]) but in this case I just want to show the different plots represent the bar chart and line.

Currently I am just trying to add aes(), is there a way to change my code so that aes() can read in a single variable to give me a legend, or can I simply add in a legend without aes() in my code?

```
ggplot(new_construction, aes(year, total_new_constructions)) +
  geom_col(aes(color=total_new_constructions), color="blue", fill="blue", legend.text = "Amount of new construction") +
  geom_line(aes(y = a + average_rental_prices*b, color=total_new_constructions), color = "orange", lwd=1.5, legend.text = "Average rental price") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Total New Constructions", breaks=seq(0, 30000, by=10000),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, name = "Average Rental Prices", breaks=seq(0,4000, by=1000))) +
  
  scale_x_continuous("Year", seq(2000, 2018))   +
  labs(title="Total New Constructions and Average Rental Prices (2000-2018)", subtitle = "Data Source: TidyTuesday R") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map a constant value on the `color` and/or `fill` aes, then set your colors and labels via `scale_color/fill_manual`.

Using some fake example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

new_construction <- data.frame(
  year = 2000:2018,
  total_new_constructions = seq(0, 3e4, length.out = 19),
  average_rental_prices = 800
)

a <- 1
b <- 10

ggplot(new_construction, aes(year, total_new_constructions)) +
  geom_col(
    aes(fill = "Bar"),
    color = "blue"
  ) +
  geom_line(
    aes(
      y = a + average_rental_prices * b,
      color = "Line"
    ),
    lwd = 1.5
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = "orange",
    labels = "Average rental price"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = "blue",
    labels = "Amount of new construction"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Total New Constructions",
    breaks = seq(0, 30000, by = 10000),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a) / b,
      name = "Average Rental Prices",
      breaks = seq(0, 4000, by = 1000)
    )
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous("Year", seq(2000, 2018, 2)) +
  labs(
    title = "Total New Constructions and Average Rental Prices (2000-2018)",
    subtitle = "Data Source: TidyTuesday R",
    color = NULL, fill = NULL
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]